# Adding character on the right side of match when match appears in isolation

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to add `ɨ` on the right side of `tʂ`, `tʂ`, `ʂ`, `ʐ`, `ts`, `ts'`, and `s` when they appear in isolation (when they are not touching other IPA characters). Note that there's a number after each of them, and the lines are surrounded by `/`.

```js
const input = `/ʊɔ3 yɛn2 tʂ2 tʂɑʊ3/
/ʊɔ3 mən5 tɕ'ʂ2 tʂɑʊ3/
/pu2 ʂ4 tʂə4 kə4/
/ʂ1/`

const output = input.replace(/(\/|[ ])(tʂ|tʂ\'|ʂ|ʐ|ts|ts\'|s)\d([ ]|\/)/g, '$&ɨ')
console.log(output)
```

Right now, this is the output:

```
/ʊɔ3 yɛn2 tʂ2 ɨtʂɑʊ3/
/ʊɔ3 mən5 tɕ'ʂ2 tʂɑʊ3/
/pu2 ʂ4 ɨtʂə4 kə4/
/ʂ1/ɨ
```

But what I want is this:

```
/ʊɔ3 yɛn2 tʂɨ2 tʂɑʊ3/
/ʊɔ3 mən5 tɕ'ʂ2 tʂɑʊ3/
/pu2 ʂɨ4 tʂə4 kə4/
/ʂɨ1/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using:

```
([/ ](?:t[ʂs]'?|[ʂʐs])(?=\d+[ /]))
```

And replace by `$1ɨ`. See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/4fkd9t/1)

---

- `([/ ]` - Open 1st capture group and match a capture forward slahs or space;

  - `(?:t[ʂs]'?|[ʂʐs])` - Non-capture group to match any of the given combinations you provided;
  - `(?=\d+[ /])` - Positive lookahead to assert position is followed by 1+ digits and another forward slash or space;
  - `)` - Close 1st capture group which is now ready for backreference in replacement.

---

```js
const input = `/ʊɔ3 yɛn2 tʂ2 tʂɑʊ3/
/ʊɔ3 mən5 tɕ'ʂ2 tʂɑʊ3/
/pu2 ʂ4 tʂə4 kə4/
/ʂ1/`

const output = input.replace(/([/ ](?:t[ʂs]'?|[ʂʐs])(?=\d+[ /]))/g, '$1ɨ')
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const input = `/ʊɔ3 yɛn2 tʂ2 tʂɑʊ3/
/ʊɔ3 mən5 tɕ'ʂ2 tʂɑʊ3/
/pu2 ʂ4 tʂə4 kə4/
/ʂ1/`

const output = input.replace(/(\/|[ ])(tʂ|tʂ\'|ʂ|ʐ|ts|ts\'|s)(\d([ ]|\/))/g, '$1$2ɨ$3')
console.log(output)
```

(included the digit in the third capture and changes the replacement text)